# For Non US resident is it better to invest in a start up as a individual or as a company?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, income-tax, starting-out-investing

What are the tax implications of investing as a company versus as an individual for foreigners (Non US resident)in the US? Which would be better for a foreigner (NON US Citizen) to invest as.

Comment: Are you asking about the US tax consequences? Are you investing in the US? Where is the company organized? Where are you residing?

Comment: Yes, i want to know about the US tax consequences. I am looking to invest in the US. The company is registered in Malaysia. I will have no direct presence in the US other than for the investments. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remember to not only worry about taxes but also think about liability.  If you have any chance of being sued, make a corporation and protect your assets.

Answer (score 0):

From the US perspective, unless a tax treaty says otherwise, it would probably be better to invest as an individual rather than as a corporation.

You need to check if the company as organized under the Malaysian law, is considered a corporation in the US. Most likely it is.

Corporations pay corporate tax rates on their US-sourced income which may be higher than the individual rates, and cannot take capital losses. Also, capital gains and dividends may get better tax treatment under individual income tax than under corporate. Last but not least, moving money out of the US as a corporation may be messier than as an individual transferring between two personal accounts.

Verify with a US licensed tax adviser (EA/CPA/Attorney) who is familiar with the Malaysian corporate law and can identify if the Malaysian company is qualifying to be treated as a disregarded entity in the US (even then it may not be as simple as for an individual for himself).

Also, keep in mind that in some of the US States, individuals may not have personal income tax (on the State level), but corporations do. If your startup is going to be operating in one of those States - you'll have to take it into account.

Comment: individuals have unlimited liability however, for that reason alone it may be better to register as at least an LLC